# How to open a fragment when user click the notification in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, notifications, fragment

I'm trying to open a fragment rather than activity if the user click the notification

here is the function for notification:

```
private fun sendNotification(nextPray: Pray) {
    log("Send Notification")
    //small view
    val collapsedView = RemoteViews(
        packageName,
        R.layout.notification_collapsed
    )
    //big view
    val expandedView = RemoteViews(
        packageName,
        R.layout.notification_expanded
    )
    val snoozeIntent = Intent(this, StopAlarm::class.java)
    val snoozePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, snoozeIntent, 0)

    val notificationIntent = Intent(this, FullAzan::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)

    val mBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID2)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.qalby_ic)
            .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
            //.setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
            .setContentTitle("It's Time for ${nextPray.name}")
            .setContentText("Let's Pray")
        
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .addAction(
                R.drawable.ic_stop,
                getString(R.string.text_stop),
                snoozePendingIntent
            )
            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID2)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
    val notification = mBuilder.build()
    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
    notificationManager.notify(100, notification)
    //startForeground(100, notification)
    log("vibrating")
    vibrate()
    log("Azan Audio Started")
    MediaPlayerManager.getInstance(applicationContext).azan(nextPray)

    
}
```

in these lines:

```
val notificationIntent = Intent(this, FullAzan::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
```

i initialized it

and called it in this line:

```
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

i want to replace "Intent(this, FullAzan::class.java)" with fragment rather than the current one which is activity, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You would need to handle that yourself, for example, by putting an extra on that `notificationIntent` that you can read in `FullAzan` and then decide which `Fragment` to show.

Comment: can you be more specific because i'm new to kotlin

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly open a `fragment` using the `Intent`, instead you should open the containing `Activity` of your fragment and pass some intent extra indicating which fragment to open and then show the appropriate fragment depending on the value of intent extra. for example, if you wanted to open a fragment which gets loaded in `FullAzan` `Activity`

```
val notificationIntent = Intent(requireContext(), FullAzan::class.java)

// Add an extra in intent indicating the fragment to open
notificationIntent.putExtra("FRAGMENT_NAME", "SOME_FRAGMENT")
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
```

Now when `FullAzan` is opened by notification click, simply check which fragment you want to open, and load that fragment

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    when(intent?.getStringExtra("FRAGMENT_NAME")){
         "SOME_FRAGMENT" -> loadSomeFragment()
         else -> // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: when i apply this and click the notification it open full white page and show nothing

Comment: You need to write your code to display the appropriate fragment, @mightyWOZ is just showing you how to pass that information to the activity. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#perform